# ListTile inside ListView is causing an error

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../providers/weather_provider.dart';

class BottomListView extends StatelessWidget {
  const BottomListView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final weatherData = Provider.of<WeatherProvider>(context).weatherData;

    final isLandscape =
        MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.landscape;
    final height = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
        50 -
        MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top);
    
    return Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          border: Border(
            top: BorderSide(width: 0.3, color: Colors.white),
          ),
          color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.2),
        ),
        height: isLandscape ? height * 0.35 : null,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 200,
                child: ListView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    children: [ListTile(title: Text('Hello'))]),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

I want to have horizontal scrollable listView with ListTiles. But without ListTile it works fine . With ListTile it is causing an error.How to solve it? I tried giving it the width but didn't work.

Error:

BoxConstraints forces an infinite width.

These invalid constraints were provided to RenderParagraph's layout() function by the following function, which probably computed the invalid constraints in question:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListTiles needs to be defined with width params explicitly using SizedBox or Container.

If you dont define width, it will throw infinite width error.

So Wrap your ListTile inside a SizedBox or Container.

Since, ListView's scrollDirection is set to Horizontal, you dont need to place it inside of a row i.e. it will show children horizontally.

If scrollDirection is set to vertical, it will show children in a Column i.e. Vertically

Also you can't do both, Use expanded and give width to a child of a row.
Using Expanded means the child will take maximum size available to it w.r.t to its parent.

Try the below code snippet

```
Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          border: Border(
            top: BorderSide(width: 0.3, color: Colors.white),
          ),
          color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.2),
        ),
        // height: isLandscape ? height * 0.35 : null,
        height: 100,

        child: ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: 200,
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text('Hello'),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 200,
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text('Hello'),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 200,
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text('Hello'),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 200,
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text('Hello'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```